# Not able to parse value using Regular Expression Extractor in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I have a HTTP Response from JMETER as :

```
[{"Id":null,"Message":"2578W,","IsError":false}]
```

I need to pass the message "2578W" into the next HTTP request. I am using the Regular Expression Extractor in JMETER. and passing the values as:
Apply to Main Sample and sub-sample

```
Field to Check : Body
Reference Name: ${Message}
Regular Expression: [{"Id":null,"Message":"(.*?),","IsError":false}]
Match No. 1
Default Value: Not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape these symbols `[]` with backslashes as they are [Regular Expressions Meta Characters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) representing character classes

So I would recommend amending your Regular Expression to look like:

```
\[{"Id":null,"Message":"(.+?),","IsError":false}\]
```

Don't forget to set "Template" to `$1$`

[image: JMeter Regular Expression]

See [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) article for more details on performing correlation in JMeter tests using regular expressions.

---

Given you getting response in JSON format you may find [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) easier to use, the relevant JSON Path query will be as simple as

```
$..Message
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the folllowing regex:

```
,"Message":"(.*)",".*
```

You can experiment easily on [this link.](https://regex101.com/) Your original regex matches much much more.